# sql query with group by to find disposed and pending assignment by student

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table called `assignment`:

```
assignment_id   student_id  report_id
--------------------------------------
25                  1       0
56                  2       10
28                  1       5
94                  1       0
75                  1       0
86                  1       0
95                  2       5
```

I'm using this SQL query to find out total number of assignment received by each student

```
select student_id as student, count(assignment_id) as total_assignment ,    
from assignment  
group by student_id 
order by student_id asc
```

Result of this query is

```
student    total_assignment
---------------------------
1                  5       
2                  2
```

In assignment table where `report_id == 0`, assignment is pending otherwise assignment is disposed. I need to also find total disposed and pending assignment by each student.

Please help me complete this above SQL query. Thanks

Comment: I guess now we know what happen after the student submit the assignment. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select student_id as student, count(*) as total_assignment,
       sum(case when report_id = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_pending,
       sum(case when report_id <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_completed
from assignment 
group by student_id
order by student_id asc;
```

As a matter of word choice:  I prefer "completed" to "disposed".  At least in American English, "disposed" has the connotation of being thrown out as garbage.

Comment: Some may be disposed to disagree.    (words ... fun stuff)